# Flutter: Perform http.put request and change state of string in JSON/API

Tags: json, api, flutter, django-rest-framework

So I have an api that has a value ("state" : "started"), I want to change to this: ("state" : "done"). If anyone have an idea on how to do this via a http.put request in Flutter, feel free to help :)

API:

```
GET /api/task/29/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
"id": 29,
"description": "Berlinmurens Fall",
"state": "started",
"assigned_users": [
    {
        "username": "hugo",
        "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
    }
],
"subtasks": []
}
```

JSON:

```
{"id":29,"description":"Berlinmurens Fall","state":"started","assigned_users":[{"username":"hugo","fullname":"Hugo Johnsson"}],"subtasks":[]}
```

Put Request:

```
putRequest() async {

String url = "--URL--";

final Map<String, dynamic> jsonDataaa = {
  "state": "done"
};

var response = await http.put(
    Uri.encodeFull(url),
    headers: { "Accept" : "application/json"},
    body: json.encode(jsonDataaa),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
);

return response;
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> jsonDataaa = {
  "id": 29,
  "description": "Berlinmurens Fall",
  "state": "done",
  "assigned_users": [
    {
      "username": "hugo",
      "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
    }
  ],
  "subtasks": []
};
```

Comment: PUT requires that the full object be sent (all required fields), so if you only want to send one field, you should use PATCH instead

Comment: The Api does not allow patch. (Check Above). Can you by any means show me how to use put? I tried to fill all the fields and nothing happens

Comment: Check above, This is what I'm trying to do!

Comment: I can't really help you with flutter as I thought it was a Django rest framework issue. But in any case, you should add all the fields if you're using PUT. And then also state what the issue is because it's not clear from the question. What is the response you get when you run the above code? what do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: My issue is that I can't change the state. I can't properly make a put request :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use patch method in flutter for sending single field.
look this link [Http-Methods in flutter](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-http-requests-in-flutter-d12e98ee1cef)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This would be example: